# Input type file com imagem pre selecionada

Tags: html, mysql

Tenho o caminho de uma imagem na base de dados ex:   admin/conteudo_admin/imagem_noticia/atletas.jpg

Tenho este input type="file" e pretendia que esta imagem estive-se selecionada

```
<input type="file"  id="imagem" name="imagem" >
```

Comment: como assim selecionada?

Comment: com este caminho estou a fazer editar no backoffice

Comment: podes definir o valor no input, com php

Comment: mas nao vai aparecer por exemplo o nome do ficheiro a frente

Comment: explique melhor o que você quer ao certo.. tá dificil de entender..

Comment: Estive a fazer uns testes. `<input type="file" id="imagem" name="imagem" value="ficheiro">` não resulta, não aparece "ficheiro". E pelo que estive a perquisar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365668/pre-populate-html-form-file-input. Não dá

Answer (score 1):

Definir isso diretamente no `..input type="file"..` não dá. Pode no entanto fazer em texto:

```
<input type="file" id="imagem" name="imagem">
<span><?php echo $imagem_da_BD; ?></span>
```

Pode também colocar a imagem logo a seguir ao input:

```
<input type="file" id="imagem" name="imagem">
<img src="<?php echo $imagem_da_BD; ?>">
```

Comment: assim nao vai aparecer por exemplo o nome do ficheiro a frente

Comment: Tente assim como está em cima